# WooCommerce Table Rates not splitting up

Tags: woocommerce-offtopic

Here is the situation. I have a Table Rate that is set up with two different product categories.

The problem is that when I do a test check out both products, I'm noticing that when I select both products, it gets the shipping rate of the first product.

How do I split up the shipping rates? Do I need to create another shipping table?

Thank you..

Answer (score 0):

Found a resolution.

The problem was that I had based the calculated rates based upon the class. Switched it to based on the line item, the rates are being calculated correctly,